# Cross Referencing Assistance?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, vlookup

So I am tasked with finding and noting the part numbers from one sheet, that includes a list of data of all part numbers of the company, and add them into or just make note that the part numbers is missing from this other data sheet. Another thing is that if the part number from the first sheet doesn't start with (C, F, L, M, R, S, V, W), it should not be noted or added to the second sheet? I know I am supposed to use VLookup somehow but I am not sure how, any assistance would be greatly obliged. I looked up cross referencing, but no luck.

EDIT: I added the changes and was able to figure out how to create a cell that determine if the the part number from the DATA document is different from the estimateslinesExport. My problem now is that the cell should only account for part numbers starting with (C, F, L, M, R, S,V, W) .If there is a way to just hide the ones that don't start with those letters automatically, that would be perfect, as the document has around 6000 part numbers. THANKS

Expectations: To add the missing part numbers that start with (C, F, L, M, R, S, V, W) from the **estimatelinesExport**  document to the **data** document.

Estimateslinesexport:

[image]

Data:

[image]

Comment: Please take the time to [read this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask). then come back and [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1442570/edit) to provide sample data, expected outcome, what you have tried and an explanation of how it fails to achieve the desired results

Comment: The question is foggy. You have 2 datasheets. One with all partno, the other with... I haven't understood! You have to find the part numbers that are missing in the first one? You can use VLookup, but you have to clone the function to each row of the second sheet. The function will write 'not found' as a result if the search will not match.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not entirely clear, but here is an attempt to answer
*(please rework your question if you do not find this answer matching your needs)*.

It appears that you have two lists with part numbers and wish to compare them, then merge missing data at least one way.

Do this:

1. create a temporary list, append the second to the first.
2. sort the list
3. use "Remove duplicates"(?) from the Data (menu or ribbon)

The temporary list now contains one sample of each item found in either of first and second lists. If you cannot use the temporary list as is...

1. Sort the first list, place the temporary list beside it.
2. With these lists in column A and B, enter
   `=IF($A$1<>$B$1;"DIFF";"")` in column C and fill it in on all lines.
3. Now it should be easy to spot differences.
4. Place the cursor on cells where a missing item needs to be filled in, hold `CTRL` and hit `+`, select to "shit cells down" to insert an empty cell so that more of the lists match.

If you have may differences, look up a "diff" utility and use it instead.
*(e.g. google "Kdiff", unless you're running Linux - where you have "diff" included among the shell utilities.)*